# Extract Tweet ID from text

Tags: bash, twitter, tweets

I have a large, 4.5M+ row CSV (commas are the separators) containing tweets. The CSV comes from some time ago, and has all manner of line breaks inside column data, characters, etc. It is likely malformed in some ways but it is difficult for me to discern exactly where and how with a file of this size.

I want to move through this CSV file as a large body of text, pull out all the Tweet IDs, and put each pulled ID into a line in a new file.

Doing this via bash, perl, Python will work fine. Can anyone help here? I can't seem to even find info on the parameters for a tweet ID, though the ones in this corpus seem to all be 17 integers.

Answer (score 1):

Since in your question the only evidence for a Tweet ID is that its an integer of length of 17, that is the only rule I am going to use.

Plus, I am going to use it as a hard-and-fast rule. Anything that is an integer of length is a Tweet ID, nothing else.

After that its a normal regular expression search.

```
import re

string = '''
12345678912345678, abcd, efgh
45645645645645645, ijkl, mnop
78944556677889900, qrst, uvwx
0, y, z
'''

m = re.findall('[0-9]{17}', string)
print(m)
```

> re.findall searches for the regular expression (first arg) in the string (second argument)
>
> (a):- [0-9] means any integer between 0 to 9
>
> (b):- {m} means the regular exp. that preceded this must repeat m number of times
>
> (a)+(b):- [0-9]{17} get me a match that has is a string of integers 0 to 9 repeated 17 times. i.e. a number of length 17

[find out more about re module in python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects)

This is as much I can help with you without knowing anything about the input file and tweet format.